# Syntax error in FROM clause VB6

Tags: sql, ms-access, datagrid, vb6, ado

I want my program to show only the active students that are in the database. If the student has Archived as No, it shows them, but if the student has Yes, it hides them. Every time I play the program, it shows me the error in `Adodc1.Refresh`:

> Syntax error in FROM clause.

Code:

```
    Dim sql As String

    connSearch.Open connstr
    Adodc1.ConnectionString = conn.connstr
    sql = "select * from Table1 where [Archived] <> 'NO'"
    Adodc1.RecordSource = sql
    Set StudentTable.DataSource = Adodc1
    Adodc1.Refresh ''''The error is in this line.''''
    Adodc1.Visible = False
```

Comment: Is really Table1 existing ? if yes try adding it in brackets : [Table1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem, i needed **adcmdText** in the code for it to work. Thankyou Microsoft Help https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/238279

```
Dim sql As String

sql = "select * from Table1 where [Active] <> 'No'"
Adodc1.ConnectionString = conn.connstr
Adodc1.CommandType = adCmdText
Adodc1.RecordSource = sql
Set StudentTable.DataSource = Adodc1
Adodc1.Refresh
Adodc1.Visible = False
```